# Cannot map asterisk (*) key in VIM correctly

Tags: vim, mapping, asterisk

I'm trying to map * for resizing windows like this in my vimrc:
`map * <C-W>-`
This doesn't work in normal mode but works when using visual mode.
(by pressing <C-W>- manually, it works in normal mode)
Is there a reason why it doesn't work with my mapping? How can I use asterisk in normal mode?

Comment: Are you sure that `*` is not already mapped to something in normal mode?

Comment: damn thanks you're right. I checked it by :verbose map and a plugin used it.

Answer (score 2):

`map * <C-W>-` is a **recursive** mapping: if anything in that mapping is already mapped to something else at the time of usage it is that something else that will be executed.

It is generally advised to use **non-recursive** mappings for most mappings *except when you purposely use another mapping in your mapping*.

The non-recursive variant of your mapping would be:

```
noremap * <C-W>-
```

Note that `:map` covers normal mode, visual mode, select mode, and operator-pending mode which may have unintended consequences. You should always use the most specific command available, in this case:

```
nnoremap * <C-W>-
```